# jQuery parse xml from restful web service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, xml, xml-parsing

I have a code for pulling data from careerbuilders api. The link works well when tested on the browser, but I can't seem to parse anything from it. Care to tell me what is wrong?

html code:

```
<div class="main">
    Companies:
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=WDHL4Z86PBQY29Z7ZQQS&Location=Canada",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser(xml)
    });

});

function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find("JobSearchResult").each(function () {
         $(".main").append(
             $(this).find("Company").text()
         );
    });

}
```

Here is a jsfiddle live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cc4SY/

Comment: what is the output of alert(xml) or console.log(xml) ? my guess is, you just need xml.find()

Comment: The only way you have for this to work is knowing if that API offers to respond in jsonp, but as they don't include the cross-domain headers in their responses I don't think they will support it (made a quick search and didn't find anything refering jsonp).
You need wrap the call to the careerbuilder's API in some other script like php, and call your php script from ajax.

Comment: This is a limitation embedded in every browser's javascript implementation. If the the site were the ajax's call is being made doesn't support jsonp nor includes the cross-domain headers there is nothing you can do for ajax to work. Only way around is writing an intermediary script and call it from ajax.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `xml` won't be defined. You have to wrap the success callback in another function which in turn will call your `xmlParser` function.

What you are doing is calling the `xmlParser` function and assigning the return value as the success callback, which is not intended. So you have wrap it in another function and call `xmlParser` from that function and in that case the xml response will be properly passed to the `xmlParser` and you will able to parse it.

The code might look like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=WDHL4Z86PBQY29Z7ZQQS&Location=Canada",
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function (response) {
                    xmlParser(response);
                }
            });
    });

function xmlParser(response){
    var xml = $.parseXML(response);
    $(xml).find("JobSearchResult").each(function () {
        $(".main").append(
            $(this).find("Company").text()
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think now it's working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=WDHL4Z86PBQY29Z7ZQQS&Location=Canada",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml)
            {
                xmlParser(xml);
            }
    });

});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cc4SY/2/

Console response: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=WDHL4Z86PBQY29Z7ZQQS&Location=Canada. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

It's a jsfiddle restriction.

Comment: Nop, its a restrition from the api.careerbuilder.com. They need to add to their responses the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" among others, so ajax could make a cross site get.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" thing. I even tried it on my localhost, still getting that restriction. D: I'll go google a bit see what comes up.

Comment: See my comment in your question please.